# Android: Calling a method which is not in an Activity by clicking a Button

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity, methods

I have 2 Java classes with 2 XML layout files in my Android Studio Project. The first class is my MainActivity class and container for the map which the second class displays. The layout works fine, but I have a Button in the XML File of my second class, which is set to call a method in my second class when clicked. But the button can only call methods from my MainActivity class. How can i let the Button call another method, let's say a method from another class than my MainActivity class?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

/Edit:

I can call the other method now, but everytime I try accessing something from the MainActivity class the app crashes. Code example:

```
public void test() { 
  TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView); 
  tv.setText("2"); 
}
```

This is the method from the second class which is called out of the MainActivity class. The call works fine, but I can't access anything from the layout. If it helps the class is a Fragment, which contains a MapView:

```
public class MapsFragment extends Fragment {
```

Comment: add codes to show what u have written.

Comment: If the second method is in an Activity class, you might be thinking about this wrong

Comment: But it isn't an activity class, it's a fragment, which is included in my MainActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object of your second class in the Mainactivity.
Then use the object to call the function of second class.

Edited -

I see that you dont need to create a function like fragment_obj.updateTextView();. I set all my view as class level objects and was able to update the textview directly.

```
fragmentObj.textViewLanguage.setText("Your Text Here!");
```

Note: If you need to perform more than one action then having a function is the way to go.

**Using a function** -
You can find the instance of Fragment by using,

For support library,

```
YourFragment fragment_obj = (YourFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().
                          findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
```

else

```
YourFragment fragment_obj = (YourFragment)getFragmentManager().
                                         findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
```

Then create a method in the Fragment that updates your TextView and call that method using fragment_obj like,

```
fragment_obj.updateTextView();
```

Comment: I tried it, but it only saves my problem partially. I can call the other method but everytime I try accessing something from the MainActivity class the app crashes. Code example:

    public void test() {
      TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView);
      tv.setText("2");
    }

This is the method from the second class which is called out of the MainActivity class. The call works fine, but I can't access anything from the layout.

If it helps the class is a MapsFragment: 

    public class MapsFragment extends Fragment {

Comment: Don't make the UI changes of a fragment from activity. But can do that but you can also set the value of the textView from the fragment itself, if that's what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to make the UI Changes via a Button, but the Button can only call a method in the activity but not in the fragment. That's my problem.

Comment: Check the edited answer. I should definitely solve your problem.

Comment: It helps me a bit, but unfortunately it doesn't completely solve my problem. The problem that i still have is, that I cannot use any resources from within my fragment. I want to accomplish a more complex goal than just editing a TextView, but if i can't even access that TextView, I can't access any other resources like Textfields or something. The Problem is, the line (see above) where i get the TextView by ID, at that point the app crashes, but it normally should put the TextView in the tv variable and let me edit it via tv.setText("").

Comment: I have no idea how to bring the text view on a class level either, because it isn't in my code at all, it is just in the XML Layout file.

Comment: Put your full code. All java n xml files in your question. So that i can edit to solve your problm

Comment: I just solved my problem by myself, all this time I didn't see that it was obvious, I just accessed the resource at my MainActivity class and passed it on to my fragment as a method parameter. 

But thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to wire an xml button to a method via xml `android:onClick`, you can do it easily via code:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // call the method
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Go in your XML code and add this property `android:onClick="OnClickMe"` , then go in your class which you want to access another method,  and add the method for controlling the Button clicks.

First declare your Button in `Oncreate`

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button);
```

Then create a method to handle the button clicks , and inside Instantiate the  class to access the Method you want. Suppose you want to access `ClassA`

```
 public void OnClickMe(View v ){

// Suppose you want to access a method from ClassA 
ClassA accessmethod = new ClassA();
// this is how you can call your method in another class
accessmethod.MethodName();

    }
```